# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: php, json

I am trying to connect to the Envato api, but every so often i get the following error:

**failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity**

Here is my code

```
$codecanyon_url = file_get_contents("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/categories:codecanyon.json");
$codecanyon_decode = json_decode($codecanyon_url, true);

foreach($codecanyon_decode['categories'] as $x=> $item) {
        echo $item['name'].' - '. $item['path'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this? It happens intermittently. I have tried to `urlencode` the url but this make no difference.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I have the same issue. What I found out so far is that if I run the API URL first in the browser it works, but it starts working from the backend as well. Do you experience the same thing? Seems like some sort of caching issue on their side.

Comment: yes if i navigate to the url in my browser, it works fine. also if i copy the url in file_get_contents, the first time it works after this i then start to get the error.

Comment: But works fine every time from browser, right?

Comment: yes that is correct!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around the issue by adding User-Agent header in the API request.

> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36

Let me know if this fixes it for you as well.

Comment: just this will do: ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0');

Comment: Sure. I just copied the user agent string from my browser.

Comment: @dan Thanks Dan. Your code helped to fix my issue. I just wasted some hours to find this :)